# Will Tor prevent internetal monitoring via our router?

Tags: anonymity

my chinese wife is spying/monitoring and blocking my internet access with what I guess is some sort of 'child monitoring' software. (...she blocked my porn..)

But I think it works directly with our in-home router.

Will Tor help with that, or will she still know?

Answer (score 0):

Routers give each computer their own internet address. However sites identify the 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 etc internet addresses because they are different by only one number. The computer you use has the internet access blocking software. Delete it. I am not aware of routers able to store software. Each computer protected by Net Nanny requires a “seat” or license. If you purchased more than 1 seat you can install Net Nanny on the same number of computers as your purchased seats.

Comment: Routers can indeed store such software and many of them come with it builtin and configurable through the web management interface.